# ECS container hangs when calling ssm API endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

It seems ECS API hangs when calling `ssm.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com`. Below is the debug results where it hangs

```
2020-06-11 22:47:10,831 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (2): ssm.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443
```

This works fine on EC2 instance. Just inside ECS task container doesn't work and connection gets timed out.

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: When you say "works fine on EC2 instance" do you mean the EC2 instance that's running the container? Or some other EC2 instance?

Comment: I mean EC2 instance that's running the container

Comment: Does your task have access to the internet? What networking mode it uses?

Comment: it's default networking mode

Comment: By "default", do you mean `bridge`? Please check your task definition before answering.

Comment: It says `If you choose <default>, ECS will start your container using Docker's default networking mode, which is Bridge on Linux and NAT on Windows. <default> is the only supported mode on Windows.` Yes so it's bridge

Comment: What do you mean by "the ECS API hangs"? Is this happening when your ECS task is being deployed? Or is it happening inside your application which is running inside the ECS task?

Comment: I didn't ask what the documentation said, I asked how your actual task definitions are configured. To diagnose a problem, you have to start with what the current situation is, not what the documentation says it could be.

Comment: Also, is your EC2 instance Linux or Windows?

Comment: It's EC2 instance Linux and it's default networking which is bridge

Comment: @MarkB when I do this `/usr/local/bin/aws ssm get-parameter --region ap-southeast-2 --name /test --with-decryption --debug` it stops at above error and doesn't go further. I tried to curl and it doesn't work. I'm thinking it might be due to some proxy that needs to be set up now...

Comment: I tried to set NO_PROXY using https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/http-proxy-docker-ecs/ instructions but when I curl from EC2 instance I get `* Uses proxy env variable https_proxy == 'http://proxy:1111'` but in the ECS task container I don't get any of those. How can I get proxy to work inside container?

Answer (score 6):

> Works fine on EC2 instance

Hmm... I think your container is a victim of IMDSv2. Please allow me to explain.

Instance metadata is data about your instance that you can use to configure or manage the running instance. Instance metadata is divided into categories, for example, host name, events, and security groups. You can query instance metadata by calling the following URL:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

On Nov 19, 2019, v2 of the Instance Metadata Service was released. One of the features introduced with EC2 Instance Metadata Service version 2 (IMDSv2) is "Protecting against open layer 3 firewalls and NATs" [1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/defense-in-depth-open-firewalls-reverse-proxies-ssrf-vulnerabilities-ec2-instance-metadata-service/) which sets a TTL (or hop limit [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live)) of 1 on low level IP packets containing the secret token so the packet can only cross one host. The TTL of 1 means that the instance is not able to forward the packet to a Docker container running on an ECS Container instance as that would be counted as another hop.

From [1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/defense-in-depth-open-firewalls-reverse-proxies-ssrf-vulnerabilities-ec2-instance-metadata-service/):

> With IMDSv2, setting the TTL value to “1” means that requests from the EC2 instance itself will work because they’re returned to the caller (on the instance) before the subtraction occurs. But if the EC2 instance has been misconfigured as an open router, layer 3 firewall, VPN, tunnel, or NAT device, the response containing the token will have its TTL reduced to zero before leaving the instance, and the packet containing the response will be discarded on its way out of the instance, preventing transport to the attacker. The information simply won’t make it further than the EC2 instance itself, which means that an attacker won’t get the response back with the token, and with it the ability to access instance metadata, even if they’ve been successful at getting past all other defenses.

A consequence of this change is Docker containers running on ECS instances in Bridge or AWSVPC mode can no longer query the metadata endpoint. The following request will timeout:

```
$ curl -X PUT -H "x-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds: 120" "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token"
```

If using AWS CLI, it has a fallback mechanism to IMDSv1 but after a long delay (5 seconds) which makes it rather unusable.

From: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3024#issuecomment-589135606 :

> From v2.575.0, the SDK is configured to default to the IMDSv2 workflow and, by default, will try three times (with a timeout of one second between attempts) to obtain the required token. If all three attempts fail, the SDK will then fall back to the IDMSv1 workflow.

### Option 1 (Use with caution)

It is possible to use the 'modify-instance-metadata-options' [3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/modify-instance-metadata-options.html) AWS CLI call on the Container Instance to change the TTL to a higher value by specifying a value for the --http-put-response-hop-limit flag.

The following AWS CLI command modifies the value to '2' when run on the EC2 instance:

```
$ aws ec2 modify-instance-metadata-options --instance-id $(curl 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --http-put-response-hop-limit 2 --http-endpoint enabled
```

... after which the curl command against token endpoint was successful from the Docker container.

A Lambda function can be invoked from Autoscaling lifecycle hook to configure the value '2' on any launching instance with ModifyInstanceMetadataOptions api call. Another option is to place this command in EC2 Instance's UserData so every instance can 'self-configure' itself with the updated hop limit. Please note that in this case, Instance profile should have associated policy with 'ec2:ModifyInstanceMetadataOptions' permission for this call to be successful.

### Option 2 (Recommended)

With regards to ECS, accessing the instance credentials from a container is not considered a best practice, instead the recommendation is to set a task role and use the AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment variable to retrieve container specific credentials from the ECS agent, by for example using the "curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI" command, up to date versions of the AWS CLI use this by default.

You can read more about the task role credentials here [4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html). A similar endpoint for task metadata is also available [5](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html).

More discussion can be found here:

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/2177
- https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/670
- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/3024